# What does the notation $\nrightarrow$ mean?

Tags: functions, notation

What does the notation $\nrightarrow$ mean in the following definition of the map function:

> **Definition 2.** A workflow specification $S$ is a tuple $(Q,top,T^\diamond,map)$ such that:
>
> - $Q$ is a set of EWF-nets,
> - $top \in Q$ is the top level workflow,
> - $T^\diamond = \bigcup_{N\in Q}T_N$ is the set of all tasks,
> - $\forall_{N_1,N_2\in Q} N_1\neq N_2 \implies (C_{N_1}\cup T_{N_1})\cap (C_{N_2} \cup T_{N_2})=\emptyset$, i.e. no name clashes
> - $map : T^\diamond \nrightarrow Q/\{top\}$  is a surjective injective function which maps each composite task onto an EWF net, and
> - the relation $\{(N_1,N_2)\in Q \times Q \,|\, \exists_{t\in dom(map_{N_1})} map _{N_1}(t)=N_2\}$ is a tree

Comment: I've found [this paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/e2c2/32f96a1d0d52d2b836e33536f3d3589170e2.pdf), and the footnote on page 9 states that this denotes a partial function. I have not encountered this notation before, but it might be standard in the field

Comment: @Wojowu Thanks, Wojowu. Would you consider to restate your comment as an answer? I'd like to accept it and close the issue.

Comment: @Wojowu I have encountered this symbol for partial functions, and also encourage you to write an answer (or find a duplicate as this might have come up before).